# Fill the table with space between the rows and the whole area

Tags: tables

I have a problem and I would like to display my table in a slightly different way. First of all, I would like to have a little more space between the individual rows and furthermore, the table is very much centred/pressed to the left. I would like to have the table take up all the space so that it looks a bit better like in the picture below. Moreover, the table is not aligned with the text.
How can I do this?

**Code**

```latex
\chapter*{Heading}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Heading}
\markboth{Heading}{Heading}

\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        Tokyo, 14.02.2022 &  & sig. Michael Test  \\
        (Plate, Date)           &  &  (Signatur)   \\          
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**What I have**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

The first row should start aligned with the text

[image]

Comment: replace the `table` environment by the `center` environment and use `\\[10pt]` after the first row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the quick comment. If I replace `table` with `center` the first row isn't aligened to the text.

Comment: Also check out tabular* and \extracolsep{\fill}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1]

\vspace{2cm}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.7\linewidth}l}
        Tokyo, 14.02.2022 &   sig. Michael Test  \\[10pt]
        (Plate, Date)           &    (Signatur)   \\          
    \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.